# Don't correctly work viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Sorry for my bad English. I have BottomNavigationView in my app such as in Facebook and viewPager to scrool the fragments with swipe but I have some problems in function onPageSelected, it always set position to 4. This is the code of MainActivity:

```
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_tests:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_courses:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_leaderboard:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_settings:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_profile).setChecked(true);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    setTitle("Tests");
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_tests);
                case 1:
                    setTitle("Courses");
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_courses);
                case 2:
                    setTitle("Profile");
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_profile);
                case 3:
                    setTitle("Leaderboard");
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_leaderboard);
                case 4:
                    setTitle("Settings");
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_settings);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() >= 3) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    } else {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    }
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentTests();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentCourses();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentProfile();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentLeaderboard();
            case 4:
                return new FragmentSettings();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

}

This is the image of app
[image]
Then it it again move me to settings .And when I tap on profile

[image]

Comment: Your (second) switch statement is in need of `break` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `break` statement in `switch case` of ViewPager onPageSelected method like below

```
     @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        setTitle("Tests");
                        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_tests);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setTitle("Courses");
                        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_courses);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setTitle("Profile");
                        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_profile);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setTitle("Leaderboard");
                        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_leaderboard);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setTitle("Settings");
                        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_settings);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spend 1 hour to do this, and I only forget to add break.

Comment: @MaierIlya happy to help you...!